# Showing images with special chars in path in map tips?

Tags: qgis, utf-8

I do show jpg images through map tip's html. But if image's path has special characters (çãõ...) then map tip is not able to render it (the path to the images is directly writen in the html).

If i edit the qml with a text editor i can correctly see the special characters, but when i open proprieties->show it shows strange symbols. if i edit again directly in the proprieties->show box, then i can see the special characters but does not yet work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the software knows you need UTF-8. Go to the menu `settings / option ...`  then go to the `advanced` tab, browse to `UI`  and ensure the key `encoding` has a value of `UTF-8`