# QGIS: symbology values not displaying numbers

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm teaching a remote QGIS (v3.24) class and one of my students encountered a problem where the symbology of a layer isn't displaying the numbers. It instead comes up as unknown symbols. I suspect it's related to some sort of language setting as this student lives in China. But does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Error issue]

Comment: Go to the `Properties → Source → Data Source Encoding` and check if the selected encoding is correct.  Check for example if the data is `UTF-8` or any encoding that is suitable for the Chinese characters.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I checked and it is indeed UTF-8. It shouldn't be displayed as Chinese characters anyway. None of the other Chinese students have this problem.

Comment: The style text label (right part of the screenshot) really look bad, as if the required font is not found. Maybe that's the problem and whatever font is used to display the classes can't handle the expected characters.

Comment: I doubt it, but see if setting the [interface](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271718/showing-images-with-special-chars-in-path-in-map-tips/271754#271754) to UTF-8 helps

Comment: Okay looks like they managed to fix the problems by changing the locale in the QGIS settings. Thanks so much for your suggestions :)